# Delete dict key via reference?

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

To delete dict element we do this:

```
del d[key]
```

Is there a way to delete dict element via reference to this key.
For example, If I do this :

```
 ref = d[key]
 del ref
```

it deletes the 'ref' variable. I want to delete the dict element, not by the key but by referenced var. To be more precise i hold the reference in another dict, like this :

```
ref[k] = d[key]
indirect_del(ref[k])
```

the reason I want this is that 'key' is too big and I dont want to store the key in the reference dict, but just hold reference to it and be able to delete the referent eventually.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Are you trying to save memory by not storing `key` twice? It's already stored once in `d`.

Comment: yes.. the key is 1KB and I rather not store it twice

Comment: If you set `ref[k] = key` it's not going to make a copy and store it twice, there'll just be two pointers to the same memory location.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least with `del`.

`del` deletes names, not objects. Objects get eventually deleted by garbage collector after no more names reference them.

But I see no problem in storing a reference to the key

```
ref = key #ref is just a reference to the key, not a key copy
del d[ref]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl references can do this, but in Python it’s impossible to delete from a `dict` except with a reference to it *and* the key, so that you can form the `del d[k]` statement.

So just store that pair in your `ref` dictionary.  Of course, if all the references are into the same `d`, you can obviously write

```
def indirect_del(x): del d[x]
```

and store just the keys.

It’s not clear what your memory concerns are about, though: objects don’t take more memory when you store them in multiple places.